# Why can't I open FSharp.Data module in Visual Studio

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have a module UserSpec defined as

```
module UsersSpec

open FSharp.Data

type schema = FSharp.Data.JsonProvider<"UserSpec.json">
```

and I have the FSharp.Data.TypeProviders nuget package installed

[image: Packages]

But I get the compile error

> Error 1   The namespace or module 'FSharp' is not
>   defined   C:\Users\egger\Workspace\Weingartner.Distribution\Weingartner.Distribution.Accounts.Spec\UsersSpec.fs   3   6   Weingartner.Distribution.Accounts.Spec

Why can't I open the module?

Answer (score 1):

Don't install nuget package **FSharp.Data.TypeProviders**. Just Install **FSharp.Data**.